# Problem getting Cakephp gigya plugin to work

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

I am using Cakephp 1.3.6 and I have installed gigya plugin as per instructions. It loads fine and I am able save the data to the database. But I get error

```
ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source gigya
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 
`var $gigya = array(
'datasource' => 'gigya'
);`
to your database.php

Comment: thanks. I added var $gigya = array( 'datasource' => 'gigya' ); but unfortunately an error pops up "ConnectionManager::loadDataSource - Unable to import DataSource class .GigyaSource".

Comment: figured it out var $gigya = array('datasource' => 'Gigya.GigyaSource'). but when i try to set status or get userinfo, it takes forever and page cannot be found.